# Returning string arrays from C into Fortran

Tags: c, pointers, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I am trying to return an array of strings from C into Fortran using "iso_c_binding". The program compiles, but gives a run-time error.
My C program :

```
#include <stdio.h>    
void ret_array(int * numStrings, char **arr2 ) {                                
    int dim1=5;    
    char *arr1[5]={"name1","name2","name3","name4","name5"};    
    arr2 = &arr1;    
    printf("%s\n",arr2[0]);    
    printf("%s\n",arr2[1]);    
    printf("%s\n",arr2[2]);    
    printf("%s\n",arr2[3]);    
    printf("%s\n",arr2[4]);    
    numStrings = &dim1;    
    printf("%s","Ending  interface :");    
    fflush(stdout);    
 }
```

My calling Fortran program

```
program main
  implicit none
  CHARACTER(LEN = 255), dimension(:), allocatable:: str2
  integer(kind = 4):: istr
  call get_arr(istr, str2)
  PRINT *, str2(1)
contains
  subroutine get_arr(n, str1)
    use iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    INTEGER(KIND = 4):: n
    CHARACTER(LEN = 255), dimension(:), ALLOCATABLE:: str1
    character(kind = c_char), pointer:: fptr(:)
    TYPE(C_PTR), DIMENSION(:), allocatable:: cptr
    integer:: len1, ii

    interface 
      subroutine ret_array(dim_len, str_arr1) bind(c)
        use iso_c_binding
        integer(c_int), INTENT(OUT):: dim_len
        TYPE(C_PTR), DIMENSION(:,:), intent(out):: str_arr1
      end subroutine
    end interface

    call ret_array(n, cptr)
    PRINT *,"Number :",n
    allocate(str1(n))
    do ii = 1, n
      call c_f_pointer(cptr(ii), fptr, [ 255 ])
      len1 = index(fptr(ii), C_NULL_CHAR)
      PRINT *,len1
      str1(ii) = TRANSFER(fptr(1:len1-1),  str1(ii))
    end do
  end subroutine
end program
```

When I run it, I get the following error.

```
name1
name2
name3
name4
name5
Ending  interface :
Program received signal SIGFPE: Floating-point exception - erroneous arithmetic operation.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7f9e86776d01 in ???
#1  0x7f9e86775ed5 in ???
#2  0x7f9e865aa20f in ???
#3  0x7f9e869aa077 in ???
#4  0x55e9a5195350 in get_arr
    at /home/test/fort_code/ret_arr.f90:27
#5  0x55e9a5195984 in MAIN__
    at /home/test/fort_code/ret_arr.f90:6
#6  0x55e9a5195a37 in main
    at /home/test/fort_code/ret_arr.f90:7
make: *** [Makefile:3: run] Floating point exception (core dumped)
```

I am new to using pointers in iso_c_binding. Can you please point out why the pointer is not being returned to Fortran program?
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: It looks like you posted your c code twice?

Comment: Thanks Timothy G. I updated to the original FORTRAN code I am using.

Comment: Well first you are making a classic C mistake of returning a pointer to a local variable, which will become a pointer to garbage once the function returns - see http://c-faq.com/malloc/retaggr.html. Second Fortran is spelt lower case, officially for over 30 years. Finally what are you really trying to do? If it is just return an array of characters it looks horribly complicated.

Comment: Just to expand on my last point on glancing at the Fortran there are definitely quite a few mistakes, including at least failure to allocate any memory for the cptr array and passing an assumed shape array (without doing any of the new f2018 stuff). Could you clarify what you are doing? Do you want to set the length of the strings on the C side?

Comment: Thank you Ian Bush. I am trying to return string arrays from a C to Fortran. I don't know the size and length of string arrays being returned. Since the development environment is gcc/gfortran 5.2, I cannot use f2018.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing `arr2` to point to the local array `arr1` and then returbning the address of the local array.

That cannot work. `arr1` is not valid after the function returns.